# React native source not compiling correctly when using mocha + babel

Tags: react-native, mocha.js, babeljs

Im having a bit of an issue after upgrading to React Native 0.30.  Using mocha, and babel I transpile the react native source before test run. I'm now seeing issues where modules cannot be found.

Here's an example:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'AssetRegistry'
```

The corresponding file can be found here https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Image/AssetSourceResolver.js#L21.  It looks as if babel cannot locate the AssetRegistry file that is local in this directory.

Comment: Typically when you upgrade and modules cannot be found, you need to clear some cache. `rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-*` `watchman watch-del-all`. If that doesn't work, be sure to clear node_modules and re-install as well.

Comment: @agmcleod thanks for the reply.  Unfortunately I tried that. I have also created a new repo with a very minimal setup to test this out.  I have a small test that imports react native and transpiles it.  Resulting in this  module not being found [react-native.js#L180](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/react-native/react-native.js#L180) .

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it turns out that react-native-maps was calling an internal react-native library.  react-native-mock has most of the internals mocked for react native however the internal library for the Image utility was not mocked.

I just used mockery to mock the library and all seems to work now.